# Core Data entities faulting when using GCD

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            for (NSDictionary* info in houses) {
                House* house = [DataManager processJSON:info]; //this method processes JSON into Core Data objects and saves them
                [self.data addObject:house];
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //update the UI based on the new House objects added to the data array

            });

        });
```

My House objects sometimes work, but often and unpredictably end up like this:

```
<House: 0x17f8b420> (entity: House; id: 0x17f71e90 <x-coredata://2826DE3A-1762-4958-8402-541D2B1754FA/House/p219> ; data: <fault>)
```

I believe this has something to do with processing the Core Data objects on a background thread, causing some kind of context conflict. But I can't find many concrete examples of using Core Data with GCD. Any advice on what I can add here to make sure the objects are not faults?

Comment: Is your main thread context the parent context of the background thread? If so, you need to save the background thread context so changes are propagated to the parent main context.

Comment: Is this problem limited to printing the objects? If your code tries to access one of the attribute values, are they available?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you SHALL NOT use some arbitrary queue where you dispatch your Core Data methods which access a particular managed object context and possibly managed objects.

A particular Managed Object Context is associated to either

- A dedicated thread (`NSConfinementConcurrencyType`)
- A *private dispatch queue* (`NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`)
- The main thread (`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`).

If your managed object context is created with the `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` concurrency policy, you need to remember the thread where you created the context and use this thread to send messages to the context and also send messages to managed objects which are registered with this context.

If the context has been created with the `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` concurrency policy, you need to ensure that messages sent to the context and managed objects registered for this context will execute on the *main thread*.

If the context has been created with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` you need to ensure that messages sent to the context and sent to the managed objects registered with this context will execute on this private dispatch queue through using  the managed object context's methods  `performBlock:` or `preformBlockAndWait:`.

This is valid for basically *all* methods - in particular accessing properties of a managed object. There are only a few exceptions, where a method can be executed anywhere irrespective of the concurrency policy, e.g. [NSManagedObject] `objectID .`